# Automorphism of two members as Generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

Let $X=\langle a,b|a^{2^m}=b^{2^n}=1,[a,b]=a^{2^{m-1}}\rangle$, $m,n\ge 2$
If $\alpha \in Aut(X)$ (Automorphism Group of $X$) is defined as
\begin{cases}
\alpha(a)=a^{2^{m-1}+1}\\
\alpha(b)=b^{2^{n-1}+1}
\end{cases}
How we can show $X=\langle\alpha(a),\alpha(b)\rangle$?

Comment: If $S$ is a set of generators of $X$ and $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $X$, then $\alpha(S)$ is again a set of generators of $X$. This has nothing to do with your specific group or automorphism.

Comment: where can I find this theorem?

Comment: Sketch of proof: If $\alpha(S)$ is not a set of generators then $\alpha$ is not surjective.